# Is there any way to see how much space i am using in my yahoo mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I have many thousands of emails in yahoo mail.
Is there any way to see how much disk space that covers

Comment: This is not computer related. Please check the FAQ for more information.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. However, for general usage this shouldn't be a problem since Yahoo offers 'unlimited' space.

Apart from that, you'd have to have all your emails in another client/service to determine their total size...